# how to assign class names for tagless ember components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**user-table.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: ''
});
```

**user-table.hbs**

```
<table>
    {{yield}}
</table>
```

**usage**

```
{{#users-table class="table table-bordered"}}
    {{#table-head}}
        {{#table-row}}
            {{table-head-cell}}
            {{table-head-cell}}
        {{/table-row}}
    {{/table-head}}
    {{#table-body}}
        {{#each users as |user|}}
            {{#table-row}}
                {{table-body-cell cellValue=user.name}}
                {{table-body-cell cellValue=user.age}}
            {{/table-row}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/table-body}}
    {{#table-foot}}
        {{#table-row}}
            {{table-head-cell}}
            {{table-head-cell}}
        {{/table-row}}
    {{/table-foot}}
{{/users-table}}
```

since i mentioned tagName for the component as empty (tagName:''), how to pass class names for that root element. is there any alternative

Comment: why dont you try `{{users-table class="table" tagName='table'}}`  ..what is holding you back ?

Comment: In that case template file will be left with just {{yield}}. Code doesnt look good

Comment: you dont need to keep `{{yield}}` in your case. remember if you use `tagName=''` then you wont get `this.$`

Comment: Leaving a yield only is much better in terms of aesthetics than what you are trying to do

Comment: i need yield as i have row and column component (updated code)

Comment: Is that a good way to break a table into that many components. I know this is not part of this question. but i want to know

Comment: You can use corresponding tagName for all the components and classNames for classes..like for users-table -  tagName='table' and for table-head - tagName='th' ....

Comment: ya i did that. i want to know if it is really needed and useful when we write table, row, column as different components. i am new to ember. so i am getting these kind of doubts

Comment: It's not mandatory. if you are going to reuse available components then this looks good to me.

Comment: LokeshCherukuri without knowing what the components do it's hard to advise, but if they don't have inner behaviour, or you don't use the same component in multiple places like @kumkanillam mentions, you might want to go with plain HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tagless components, as the name says, don't have a tag, so you can't stick classes on them. They also don't have event handling, as there's no element to register the handlers on.

The suggestions in the comments are on a good track, use `tagName="table"` and have only a `{{yield}}` in the component template:

```
// user-table.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'table'
});
```

```
// user-table.hbs
{{yield}}
```

That seems to make better use of Ember functionality than alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass classNames to tagless components like so ([Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/75ca7d2db441b437a63b24c0a5e65597?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.tag-less.hbs)):

```
// user-table.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: ''
});

// user-table.hbs
<table class="{{class}}">
  {{yield}}
</table>

// usage
{{#users-table class="table table-bordered"}}...{{/users-table}}
```

The nice thing about tagless components is that it is clear from the template what the top-level element of the component is, you don't have to look up the javascript file.